# ggplot2 sort data in stack percent barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in a csv file in the following format

```
,BC1,BC10,BC11
1,2432,420,18
2,276,405,56
3,119,189,110
4,90,163,140
5,206,280,200
6,1389,1080,1075
7,3983,3258,4878
8,7123,15828,28111
9,8608,48721,52576
10,9639,44725,55951
11,8323,45695,32166
12,2496,18254,26600
13,1524,8591,18583
14,7861,1857,1680
15,10269,5165,4618
16,13560,64636,63262
```

I acquire the data in the following way

```
data <- read.csv(file="file.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
data <- data[,2:ncol(dat)]
```

Then transform it

```
datam <- melt(cbind(data,ind=rownames(data)),is.var = c('bind'))
```

Then I create a stacked percent plot

```
ggplot(datam,aes(x = variable, y = value,fill = ind)) + 
geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

To which I get:

[image]

I am trying to order the values in the legend that should go (1...16) instead of 1,10,...,16,2...,9. The color order is correct in the legend though. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `ind` (your fill variable) is being sorted as a string factor.

You can convert `ind` to numeric and then use it as the fill argument:

```
datam$ind <- as.numeric(datam$ind)
ggplot(datam, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=factor(ind))) + ...
```

However this does give `factor(ind)` as the title for the legend. You could do:

```
datam$ind <- factor(as.numeric(datam$ind))
ggplot(datam, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=ind)) + ...
```

Or, you could just use `scale_fill_discrete('My Legend Name')` and avoid having to convert `datam`, e.g.:

```
ggplot(datam, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=factor(as.numeric(ind)))) + ... +
      scale_fill_discrete('legend name')
```

#### Edit

The ordering of the legend labels is determined by `levels(datam$ind)`:

```
> levels(datam$ind)
[1] "1"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8" 
[16] "9"
```

That's why you originally got the string-wise order.
By doing `factor(as.numeric(ind))`, `levels(datam$ind)` got re-sorted in numeric order.

So to specify them going from 16 to 1, say, you can do:

```
lvls <- levels(datam$ind) # "1" "10" "11" ...
lvls <- sort(as.numeric(lvls)) # 1 2 3 4 ..
lvls <- rev(lvls)              # 16 15 14 13 ...
# re-level datam$ind according to lvls:
datam$ind <- factor(datam$ind, levels=lvls)

# now we can plot!
ggplot(datam, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=ind)) + ...
```

Hmm, that did change the colours/stacking order though. I'm unsure how to have the labels go one way but the stacking go the other -- ggplot always has them in sync (ie if labels are 1:16, then so is the stacking order). Re switching the colours around, I'm sure there's some ggplot way to reverse the colour scale, probably via `scale_colour_manual` (as that's just a cosmetic change) - I don't know how to do that myself though.

Comment: this works great! Any clues on how to invert the legend. In other words: instead of 1 and its respective color be at the top of the lengend, I would like 16 and its color at the top and 1 and its color at the bottom. Thanks again

Comment: I've just realised, the ordering is determined by  `levels(datam$ind)` - will update answer.

Comment: Thanks @mathematical I will asked the legend stacking order in another post.

Comment: turn out you only need "guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))"